# Angularjs Autosave input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to auto save my text area control 5 seconds after last change and to display the dirty flag status too.

So when I start typing the dirty flag should be true and if I stop typing for 5 seconds, I should send the latest value to the back-end code and change dirty flag to false.

I am aware of `ng-model-option` and the debounce option. It is a good solution for me except that would not change the dirty flag. The `ng-change` triggers after the timeout of 5 secs not at the beginning of the change.
A perfect solution for me would be a delay (debounce) inside `ng-change` not before so I can catch the change state.

Any idea how I can handle that?

Comment: So you are looking for two events correct? An event to fire immediately when a change occurs, and another 5s after the last change?

Comment: @IthinkIcancode yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating a directive that might help you. Please check the code below.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.myModel = 'Model';
    }
  ])
  .directive('delayBind', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
      return {
        scope: {
          ngModel: "="
        },
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          scope.timeout;
          var parser = function(value,oldValue) {
            scope.value=value;
            if (scope.timeout) {
              $timeout.cancel(timeout);
            }
            timeout = $timeout(function() {
              scope.ngModel=scope.value;
              ctrl.$setPristine();
              scope.$apply();
            }, 5000);
            return ctrl.$modelValue;
          }
          ctrl.$parsers.push(parser);
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <form name='MyForm'>
    {{myModel}}
    <br/>
    <input name='MyModel' type="text" delay-bind ng-model="myModel" />
      <br>
      {{MyForm.MyModel.$dirty}}
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One more thing. i want to use input inside ng-repeat. So i tried this code i got an error timeout is not defined. Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe this should work even if used in ng-repeat. Please check you are injecting $timeout properly

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it is by using both ngChange and $timeout. Basically, you would use ngChange for the instant status change, then inside the change function create a $timeout function which runs for another 5 seconds after the last change.

It might look something like this:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){   

var timeout;
$scope.instant = false;
$scope.delayed = false;

//INSTANT & DELAY Function
$scope.change = function(){       
    $scope.instant = true;

    if(timeout) {
        $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    }
    timeout = $timeout(function(){
        $scope.delayed = true;
    }, 5000);

 });
```

You would then call `change()` in the ngChange directive.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uasLf4xy/)